# Spring and Hibernate - No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xxx

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate with Spring, but I got some difficulties with that. I'm not sure where I should searching source of this problem, maybe I just paste screen with my project's architecture with code.

[image: project]

FlowerDAO:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="flowerDao")
 @RequestScoped
 @Component
 public class FlowerDAOImpl implements FlowerDAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="flowerproject")
EntityManager entityManager;

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

private DataSource dataSource;


public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public FlowerDAOImpl(){
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("flowerproject");
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@Override
public Set<Flower> findAll() {
    TypedQuery<Flower> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Flower.findAll", Flower.class);
    return (Set<Flower>) query.getResultList();
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="flowerproject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/flowersdb" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="flowerDAO" class="org.damian.dao.FlowerDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

   <mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.flowerproject.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.flowerproject.dao" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/flowersdb" />
     <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a bean in the beans.xml file that references the persistence.xml file.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="flowerproject" />
        <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Where the persistance.xml file should be located in the resources folder. Also there is duplicated connection information in the persistance.xml and in the dataSource. Depending on how you want to do it, one should prob be removed.

Comment: I added this code in beans.xml, but still doesn't work. I just want to use EntityManager in order to manage all database transactions in the simplest way